# Target 4.1 devices from latest Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-4.2

So latest update came out for iOS today and although I've run into this before I've sort of managed but now that I'm doing a lot of testing it is driving me nuts.

Is there a way to still deploy to devices running 4.1? I can't set the project settings to any other base SDK other than 4.2 and I can't deploy to devices running 4.2 if I don't upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In the Build Settings, there's a value called "iOS Deployment Target". You can set this to an older version of iOS. Note that this does not prevent you from using new features of iOS 4.2, so you have to be careful, as if you do so it will throw a runtime error on the older OS.

Comment: heh, I actually changed that but thought it would allow me to lower the min SDK, guess not.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a couple of places, and the settings can be different for your Debug, Release and Deployment configs.

So you can go to:
Project info
 - Deployment - iOS deployment target. ('Delete' if it's bold and it will go to the default of the base SDK)

These are overridden by the target settings, so check them too.
Target (double click on the target icon)
 - Deployment - iOS deployment target

This way you can do your debugging on 4.2 or 4.1 without changing your release build config until you have any bugs resolved!